# Authorize.Net verify credit card AIM and ARB

Tags: php, authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb, authorize.net-aim

Im using the authorize.net recurring transaction. 
What Im trying to do is give the an option to check off a donation if they want it recurring for the next 12 months.

So before the ARB - I want to verify the card but 0.00 isn't a valid amount. so if i made the amount 0.01 - how can I void the transaction after the card is verified?

Also - when a subscription is made I dont get an email from authorize.net telling me a transaction was made like when a regular transaction is processed.

My code:

```
$authorization = new AuthnetAIM($apilogin, $apitranskey, true);
$authorization->setTransaction($creditcard, $expiration, '0.01');
$authorization->setTransactionType('AUTH_ONLY');
$authorization->process();
if ($authorization->isApproved())
{
$subscription = new AuthnetARB($apilogin, $apitranskey, AuthnetARB::USE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);
    // Set subscription information
    $subscription->setParameter('amount', $amount);
    $subscription->setParameter('cardNumber', $creditcard);
    $subscription->setParameter('expirationDate', $expiration);
    $subscription->setParameter('firstName', $business_firstname);
    $subscription->setParameter('lastName', $business_lastname);
    $subscription->setParameter('address', $business_address);
    $subscription->setParameter('city', $business_city);
    $subscription->setParameter('state', $business_state);
    $subscription->setParameter('zip', $business_zipcode);
    $subscription->setParameter('email', $email);

    // Set the billing cycle for every three months
    $subscription->setParameter('interval_length', 1);
    $subscription->setParameter('startDate', date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 months")));

    // Create the subscription
    $subscription->createAccount();

    // Check the results of our API call
    if ($subscription->isSuccessful())
    {
        // Get the subscription ID
        $subscription_id = $subscription->getSubscriberID();
        Send_email();
    }
    else
    {
        $transError = 'your subscription was not created';
        $hasError = true;

    }
}
else if ($authorization->isDeclined())
{
    $transError = 'This card is not valid';
        $hasError = true;
}

}
catch (AuthnetARBException $e)
{
    $transError =  'There was an error processing the transaction. Here is the error message:<br/> ';
    echo $e->__toString();
    $hasError = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is 0.00 a valid amount, but if you're just trying to verify a credit card is legitimate you are required by Visa and Mastercard to use that amount. A few years ago they stopped allowing pre-auths of any real value to be done for this reason. I think there are fines for merchants who fail to do so.

Having said that, if you're going to take the "charge $.01 and then void the transaction" route, the following code should work:

```
$transaction_id = $authorization->getTransactionID();
$void = new AuthnetAIM($apilogin, $apitranskey, true);
$void->setTransactionType("VOID");
$void->setParameter('x_trans_id', $transaction_id);
$void->process();
```

Comment: Thanks man! - im using your tutorial and when i leave the amount set to 0.00 it throws me this error: "Required information for transaction processing omitted: dollar amount"

Comment: Interesting. Maybe things have changed as it's been a while since I've been involved in merchant account related stuff. But if you're getting that error and .01 works then definitely take that route.

Comment: So i place the new code right after the authorization? I got an email for a receipt for 0.01 - does this mean it will void it by th eend of the day?

Comment: Place it any time after `if ($authorization->isApproved()) {`. It will then be voided immediately and the customer will never see it on their statement.

Comment: ok i put it in - im just not sure where it will reflect the voided transaction. Is it possible to set an end date of the subscription? - I only want it for each month for 12 months

Comment: use `$subscription->setParameter('totalOccurrences', 12);` to have it run for only 12 months (i.e. 12 payments). The voided transaction should appear in the Authnet control panel. But that's about it for an audit trail.

Answer (score 3):

With the new SDK for authorize this would work

```
$authorize = new AuthorizeNetAIM(self::AUTHNET_LOGIN, self::AUTHNET_TRANSKEY);
$authorize->setFields(array(
        'amount' => '0.01',
        'card_num' => $cardNumber,
        'exp_date' => $expDate
));

$response = $authorize->authorizeOnly();
if ($response->response_code == 1) {
        // good card
}else{
     // bad card
}
```